# How to get a password for whatsapp API (PHP)?

Tags: php, whatsapi

I use this code

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
require_once('whatsapp_whatsapi_config.php');

$destinationPhone = 'xxxx';

$w = new WhatsProt($userPhone,0, $userName, $debug);
$w->Connect();
$w->LoginWithPassword($password);
$message = 'WhatsApp';
$w->Message($destinationPhone, $message);
echo "Mensaje enviado exitosamente";
?>
```

and this error displayed

```
  PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'LoginFailureException' in       /var/www/html/whats/src/whatsprot.class.php:2274
Stack trace:
/var/www/html/whats/src/whatsprot.class.php(552): WhatsProt->doLogin()
/var/www/html/whats/whatsapp_whatsapi_send.php(13): WhatsProt->loginWithPassword('Mu7q0hq/vRSLFCU...')
{main}
  thrown in /var/www/html/whats/src/whatsprot.class.php on line 2274
```

I tried use the WART app but the password generated is incorrect

Comment: your question doesnt make much sense - what exactly is your problem?

Answer (score 1):

Add a try-catch clause on the line that has `$w->LoginWithPassword($password);` and use the getMessage() method on the exception to see what the error message is, and what might be wrong with your login